# When launching a Twisted application via twistd, how to send command line arguments to the application?

Tags: python, twisted

When launching a Twisted application like this,

```
twistd -y application.py
```

how can you send application specific command line arguments, e.g.

```
twistd -y application.py app_arg1 app_arg2 --app_flag
```

or someting similar?

What happens with the syntax above is that `twistd` will try to interpret all the arguments for itself (i.e. arguments to `twistd`) and thus (typically) fail with a bad-command-line-argument message.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass arguments to a tac file (application.py is a tac file, even though its name does not reflect this, since you are using it with the -y option).

A tac file **is** configuration.  It doesn't **take** configuration.

If you want to be able to pass command line configuration information to your application, you probably want to write a `twistd` *plugin* instead of a tac file.

See [the plugin howto](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tap.html).